# Python elementwise addition from a dict

Tags: python, logic

I have a dictionary in the form.

```
dictName = {'Hepp': [-1,0,1], 'Fork': [-1,-1,-1], 'Dings': [0,0,1]}
```

and I basically want to pull out the values ( the lists )

and add them together elementwise and get a vector as a result, like

```
[-2,-1,1]
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to code this, and all examples I have found for adding lists assumes that I can make it into tuples, but I might have to add like 100 lists together.
Can anyone of you guys help out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension, and zip:

```
[sum(t) for t in zip(*dictName.itervalues())]
```

Comment: You don't need to do the inner comprehension `[sum(t) for t in zip(*dictName.itervalues())]` works just fine.

Comment: Yup, that way is better!  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but I got this error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'"

I am using Python 3.3.2, i should maybe mention that